# Open an url without using Browser using excel on Macbook

Tags: excel, vba

Basically I want to open an URL where the browser windows doesn't show up to the user and fetch the output. I'm in the process of writing a Function need help. I'm trying to do this in Macbook.

Answer (score 0):

if you turn off screen updating for this part of the process would that work?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

your code for the url

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Actually I need the Code to open URL without opening the Browser.

I have used the below shared Code's its not helping

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & Y_API_URL, Destination:=dDest)
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .SaveData = True
   End With

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "https://www.google.com"

Comment: And this
Sub test()
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    With Worksheets(1)
        Set h = .Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=.Range("A1"), _
            Address:="http://www.macnn.com")
        h.Follow
        h.Delete
        .Range("A1").Clear
    End With
End Sub

its Opens the browser but I'm not able to Close the Browser hence looking for something which fetch information without opening browser